Installation of Omnetpp 4.6 on ubuntu 20.04 error
I am trying to install omnetpp 4.6 on ubuntu 20.04, but i have faced an error win executing the follwoing command:
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ bison flex perl \tcl-dev tk-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev default-jre \doxygen graphviz libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 openmpi-bin \libopenmpi-dev libpcap-dev
the error is:
E: Unable to locate package
E: Unable to locate package
E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package
Can you please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Where did you get the instructions? Are you trying to build the original (2014) 4.6 or the newer (2023) 4.6.1 that "makes it possible to build and use the now 9-year-old package in today's software environments" ?
